# Using the greedy route parameter in the middle of a route definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create routes which follow the structure of a tree navigation system, i.e I want to include the entire path in the tree in my route. So if I had a tree which looked like this

- Computers

  - Software

    - Development
    - Graphics
  - Hardware

    - CPU
    - Graphics cards

Then I would like to be able to have routes that looks like this

- site.com/catalog/computers/software/graphics

This, on it's own is not hard and can be caught by a route which looks like this

- catalog/{*categories}

However I want to be able to add the product information at the end of that URL, something like this

- site.com/catalog/computers/software/graphics/title=Photoshop

Which would mean I would requite routes that were defined like the following examples

- site.com/{*categories}/title={name}
- site.com/{*categories}

However the first of these routes are invalid since nothing else can appear after a greedy parameter such as {*categories} so I'm a bit stuck. I've been thinking of implementing regex routes or perhaps use IRouteContraint to work my way around this but I can't think of a decent solution that would enable me to also use the **Html.ActionLink(...)** method to generate outbount URLs which filled in both {*categories} and {name}

Any advice is greatly apprechiated!

*Some of you may have seen a similar question by me yesterday but that was deleted, by me, since I've since given it more thought and the old question contained incomplete descriptions of my problem*

**UPDATE 2008/11/26** I posted the solution at http://thecodejunkie.blogspot.com/2008/11/supporting-complex-route-patterns-with.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes ignore query string parameters. But at the same time, query string parameters are passed in to an action method as long as there isn't a route URL parameter of the same name. So I would use just the second route, and pass in title via the query string.

Another option is more complicated. You write a custom route that derives from Route and override the GetRouteData method so that it parses the value of "categories" (something like RouteData.Values["categories"] and then add the parsed data to the route value dictionary (RouteData.Values["title"] = parsedTitle.

Comment: If I used a querystring parameter then would Html.ActionLink be able to render the parameter back out again, same for a custom route? A custom Route is fine, I just have to figure out where to begin.

PS. Check your blog mail, you've got an interview request mail waiting a couple of days :-)

Comment: It took some research (reflector for the win!) but I managed to implement my custom route to handle this and not only that, but it gave me a new understanging on how routing works.

I'll update this post with a link to my blog once I've written up on how I solved it! Thanks Phil for the hints!

Answer (score 4):

### Greedy segment anywhere in the URL

I've written `GreedyRoute` class that supports greedy (catch all) segment anywhere in the URL. It's been a while since you needed it, but it may be useful to others in the future.

It supports any of the following patterns:

- `{segment}/{segment}/{*greedy}` - this is already supported with default `Route` class
- `{segment}/{*greedy}/{segment}` - **greedy in the middle**
- `{*greedy}/{segment}/{segment}` - **greedy at the beginning**

You can read all the details [on my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) and get the code as well.