# Repeating a Parameter in a ASP.NET MVC Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to write a route that matches the following URL format:

/category1/category2/S/

where the number of categories is unknown, so there could be 1 category or there could be 10 (1..N).

I cannot use a catch all becuase the categories are not at the end of the URL.

I am actually routing to a web form here (using Phil Haack's example http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx), but that is beside the point really.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I found the answer here to be more useful: [Using the greedy route parameter in the middle of a route definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301230/using-the-greedy-route-parameter-in-the-middle-of-a-route-definition)

The blog post linked to in the question was extremely useful: http://www.thecodejunkie.com/2008/11/supporting-complex-route-patterns-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible but you could try work around it using this route:

{categories}/S

Then split the categories using the '/' character yourself.

I made a site where I just fixed it to 1-3 categories by registering 3 routes, but I had to work around a lot of things and wasn't really happy with it afterwards.

EDIT: Using S/{*categories} will catch the categories. You can only use it at the end of the URL.

Comment: I did actually try the {categories}/S route, but it doesn't match. If I use a different delimiter betweeen the categories (e.g. a dash: /category1-category2/S/) then it seems to work fine. Trouble is I cannot change the delimeter, I have to use the '/'.

Answer (score 0):

### Exactly what you need(ed)

This is a long time lost shot, but I seem to have exactly what you need. I've written a `GreedyRoute` class that **allows greedy segment anywhere in the URL** (at the beginning, in the middle or at the end - which is already supported).

You can read all details [on my blog](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) as well as getting the code of this particular class.

The main thing is it supports any of these patterns:

- `{segment}/{segment}/{*segment}`
- `{segment}/{*segment}/{segment}`
- `{*segment}/{segment}/{segment}`

It **doesn't support multiple greedy segments** though (which is of course possible as well but has some restrictions that should be obeyed in that scenario), but I guess that's a rare example where that could be used.