# ASP.net webform url route flexible?

Tags: asp.net

I use Url Route .net4 and I want to use flexible path in my URL address.
I define a URL Route for re size Images :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("thumbnail", "showthumbnail/{size}/{src}", "~/ShowThumbnail.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { { "size", 100 }, { "src", "" } });
```

and images maybe in to 1 or 2 or  3 subfolder:

http://localhost/200/folder1/folder2/folder3/image1.jpg
http://localhost/200/folder1/image1.jpg

How can I do that?

Comment: is your folder depth is 3 or it could be even more?

Comment: if it could be of any depth. check out greedy parameters in url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301230/using-the-greedy-route-parameter-in-the-middle-of-a-route-definition

Comment: Doesn't your route do what you intend it to?  Looks good to me.  Please elaborate and I will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ResolveClientURL() to access the exact image path in the page which is routed as given below:

```
<img  src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/abc.jpg") %>' />
```

Normal way of giving 'src' value will not work in all cases. Same goes with javascript also.

Please check my blog on the same at the following link.

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-access.html